# Check number in another file if in range using shell script

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed, grep

I have two files (fileA and fileB). FileA contains the list of numbers and fileB contains the number range.

fileA

```
  446646452
  000000001
  63495980020
```

fileB (range_from and range_to)

```
  22400208, 22400208
  446646450,    446646450
  63495980000,  63495989999
```

OUTPUT MUST BE

```
  63495980020
```

In sql script its just like

```
 select *
 from fileB
 where 446646452 between Range_from and Range_To
```

How can I do it using shell script?

Comment: Read `fileB` into two `awk` arrays, `from` and `to`. Then when you're reading `fileA`, loop over the from/to arrays. If the current value is between them, print it.

Comment: The from and to values on the first 2 lines of `fileB`  are identical - is that intentional?

Comment: Do the lines of `fileA` only need to be checked against the _single_ range on the _corresponding_ line of `fileB`, or against _all_ ranges (i.e., if it falls into _at least one_ range)?

Comment: should be checked against all ranges

Comment: Please add this clarification to your question (and mark it as an edit).

Comment: @John1024: I think the desired logic is: _check_ against _all_ ranges to see if the number falls into _at least 1_ of them. It would certainly have helped to clarify this up front.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per clarification from the OP, each value in `fileA` should be checked against *all* ranges in `fileB` to see if it falls into *at least one* range.
`>=` and `<=` logic for range checking is assumed (i.e., values that coincide with the range endpoints are included).

```
awk -F', +' '
  # 1st pass (fileB): read the lower and upper range bounds
 FNR==NR { lbs[++count] = $1+0; ubs[count] = $2+0; next }
  # 2nd pass (fileA): check each line against all ranges.
 { 
   for(i=1;i<=count;++i) {
    if ($1+0 >= lbs[i] && $1+0 <= ubs[i]) { print; next }
   }
 }
' fileB fileA
```

- `awk` is used to read both files, using separate passes:

  - `FNR==NR` is true for all lines from `fileB`; parallel arrays for the lower bounds (`lbs`) and upper bounds (`ubs`) of the ranges are built up; thanks to `next`, no further processing is applied to `fileB` lines.
  - The subsequent `{...}` block is then only applied to lines from `fileA`.
  - Each value from `fileA` is checked against all ranges, and as soon as a match is found, the input line is printed and processing proceeds to the next line.
  - To ensure that all tokens involved are treated as *numbers*, `+0` is added to them.

Comment: I tried the script, the problem is when the value from fileA is equal to range_from of fileB, it doesn't print.

Comment: @newbie: I've made the script more robust by ensuring treatment of all token as numbers, maybe that helps - try again. From your question it's not clear whether there's leading whitespace or not.

Answer (score 2):

### Printing Numbers That Match Any of the Ranges

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{low[NR]=$1+0; hi[NR]=$2+0;next} {for (i in low)if ($1>low[i] && $1<hi[i]){print $1;next}}' fileB fileA
63495980020
```

### How it works

- `FNR==NR{low[NR]=$1+0; hi[NR]=$2+0;next}`

  When reading in the first file, `fileB`, save low end of the range in the array `low` and the high end in the array `hi`.
- `for (i in low)if ($1>low[i] && $1<hi[i]){print $1;next}`

  When reading in the second file, `fileA`, check the number against each range.  If it satisfies any of the ranges, then print it and skip to the `next` line.

### Printing Numbers That Match Their Respective Range

```
$ paste fileA fileB | awk '$1>$2+0 && $1<$3+0{print $1}'
63495980020
```

Note that only 63495980020 is printed.  446646452 is not between 22400208 and 22400208, so it is omitted.

#### How it works

The utility `paste` combines the files like this:

```
$ paste fileA fileB 
  446646452       22400208, 22400208
  000000001       446646450,    446646450
  63495980020     63495980000,  63495989999
```

The first column is the number we are interested in while the second column is the low value of the range and the third the high value.  We want to print the first value, `$1`, if it is between the second and third.  To test if it is bigger than the second, we might try:

```
$1>$2
```

However, to assure that `awk` is treating the fields as numbers, not strings, we perform addition on one of the numbers like this:

```
$1>$2+0
```

Similarly, to test if the first number is smaller than the third:

```
$1<$3+0
```

Putting those two tests together with a print command yields:

```
$1>$2+0 && $1<$3+0 {print $1}
```

This test does strictly *between*.  Depending on your requirements, you may prefer:

```
$1>=$2+0 && $1<=$3+0 {print $1}
```

Comment: you've got the point but values should be checked against all ranges not only in its corresponding line.

Comment: @newbie If that is the case, then why does the expected output include 63495980020?  It is not in the range from 22400208 to 22400208.

Comment: + for the clever `paste` solution; given that lines in `fileA` seem to contain a single token only, you can probably drop the `{print $1}` part.
Strictly speaking, the `+0` to force conversion to a number is only required after `$2`, because `$2` contains a trailing `,`.

Answer (score 1):

Old fashion script

```
sed 's/,[[:space:]]*/ /' fileB \
 | while read LowVal HighVal
    do
      while read ThisLine
       do
         [ ${ThisLine} -ge ${LowVal} ] && [ ${ThisLine} -le ${HighVal} ] && echo "${ThisLine}"
       done < fileA
    done
```